# Use Java stream API to summarize data like SQL GROUP BY

Tags: java, sum, java-stream

With SQL I can write this to summarize data:

```
SELECT sum(f1), sum(f2), f3, f4 FROM TABLEX GROUP BY f3, f4
```

This returns a list with 4 values in each row: sum1, sum2, v3, v4

For example: this is what in table:

```
1, 2, a, b
1, 2, a, b
2, 2, c, d
2, 2, c, d
3, 4, c, d
```

The result will be:

```
2, 4, a, b
7, 8, c, d
```

Now assume that instead of a database table, I have data in a Java List of objects with variables f1,f2,f3,f4. Is there a function in Java stream API that can summarize this list based on f3, f4?

Comment: Please specify what are f1,f2,f3,f4 variables?

Comment: f1,f2 are double values. f3,f4 can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this with the JDK's `Stream` API only isn't really straightforward as other answers have shown. [This article explains how you can achieve the SQL semantics of `GROUP BY` in Java 8](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/01/23/how-to-translate-sql-group-by-and-aggregations-to-java-8/) (with standard aggregate functions) and by using [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), a library that extends `Stream` for these use-cases. [This article shows how other SQL clauses can be mapped to Java 8 Streams](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/08/13/common-sql-clauses-and-their-equivalents-in-java-8-streams/)

Given your SQL query:

```sql
SELECT sum(f1), sum(f2), f3, f4 FROM TABLEX GROUP BY f3, f4
```

You'd first have to create a named tuple `X` ([as also explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402130/521799)):

```java
public class X {
    final Double f1;
    final Double f2;
    final Object f3;
    final Object f4;

    public X(Double f1, Double f2, Object f3, Object f4) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.f2 = f2;
        this.f3 = f3;
        this.f4 = f4;
    }
}
```

And then, write:

```java
import static org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple.tuple;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.jooq.lambda.Seq;
import org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple;
import org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple2;

// ...

Map<
    Tuple2<Object, Object>, 
    Tuple2<Double, Double>
> map =

// FROM TABLEX
Seq.of(
    new X(1.0, 2.0, "a", "b"),
    new X(1.0, 2.0, "a", "b"),
    new X(2.0, 2.0, "c", "d"),
    new X(2.0, 2.0, "c", "d"),
    new X(3.0, 4.0, "c", "d"))

// GROUP BY f3, f4
.groupBy(
    x -> tuple(x.f3, x.f4),

// SELECT SUM(f1), SUM(f2)
    Tuple.collectors(
        Collectors.summingDouble(x -> x.f1),
        Collectors.summingDouble(x -> x.f2)
    )
);
```

A call to

```java
System.out.println(map);
```

Will then yield

```
{(c, d)=(7.0, 8.0), (a, b)=(2.0, 4.0)}
```

#### Without the jOOλ dependency

If you don't want to create an external dependency, all you have to do is create your own `Tuple2` class:

```java
public class Tuple2<T1, T2> {
    final T1 t1;
    final T2 t2;
    // Constructors, toString, equals(), hashCode(), etc.
}
```

... add your own tuple collector:

```
static <T, A1, A2, D1, D2> Collector<T, Tuple2<A1, A2>, Tuple2<D1, D2>> collectors(
    Collector<T, A1, D1> collector1
  , Collector<T, A2, D2> collector2
) {
    return Collector.<T, Tuple2<A1, A2>, Tuple2<D1, D2>>of(
        () -> tuple(
            collector1.supplier().get()
          , collector2.supplier().get()
        ),
        (a, t) -> {
            collector1.accumulator().accept(a.v1, t);
            collector2.accumulator().accept(a.v2, t);
        },
        (a1, a2) -> tuple(
            collector1.combiner().apply(a1.v1, a2.v1)
          , collector2.combiner().apply(a1.v2, a2.v2)
        ),
        a -> tuple(
            collector1.finisher().apply(a.v1)
          , collector2.finisher().apply(a.v2)
        )
    );
}
```

And replace `Seq` by `Stream` and `groupBy()` by `collect()` and `Collectors.groupingBy()`

Comment: Somebody can show me, which maven dependencies and imports I have to use to repeate your example with jOOλ?

Answer (score 2):

As OP said:

> `f1,f2` are double values. `f3,f4` can be anything.

So let's Consider this class:

```
public class TABLEX {
   double f1;
   double f2;
   Object f3;
   Object f4;
   //getters and setters
}
```

---

Example of list of `TABLEX`

```
List<TABLEX> list = new ArrayList<TABLEX>();
list.add(new TABLEX(1, 2, "a", "b"));
list.add(new TABLEX(1, 2, "a", "b"));
list.add(new TABLEX(2, 2, "c", "d"));
list.add(new TABLEX(2, 2, "c", "d"));
list.add(new TABLEX(3, 4, "c", "d"));
```

---

*Equivalent of `SELECT sum(f1) FROM TABLEX GROUP BY f3, f4`:*

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Double>> sumF1 = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        TABLEX::getF3,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(TABLEX::getF4,
                                Collectors.summingDouble(TABLEX::getF1))));
System.out.println(sumF1);
```

*Output:*

```
{a={b=2.0}, c={d=7.0}}
```

---

*Equivalent of `SELECT sum(f2) FROM TABLEX GROUP BY f3, f4`:*

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Double>> sumF2 = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        TABLEX::getF3,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(TABLEX::getF4,
                                Collectors.summingDouble(TABLEX::getF2))));
System.out.println(sumF2);
```

*Output:*

```
{a={b=4.0}, c={d=8.0}}
```

**EDIT:**

*To get the expected result*

```
sumF1.forEach((f3, m) -> m.forEach((f4, sum) -> System.out.println(sum
                + " " + sumF2.get(f3).get(f4) + " " + f3 + " " + f4)));
```

*Output:*

```
2.0 4.0 a b
7.0 8.0 c d
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. The goal is to get a list of double values `List<double> db = list.stream.SUM_FUNCTION(TABLEX::getF3,TABLEX::getF4).`. Is there a function SUN_FUNCTION that can do this?

Comment: You mean List<Map<Double,Double>>?

Comment: The result should be List<Double> with 2 elements in it.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to make it more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to compute the sum of all attributes F3 and F4 (without grouping them). The simplest way is with 2 pipelines:

```
double sum1 = list.stream().mapToDouble(TABLEX::getF1).sum();
double sum2 = list.stream().mapToDouble(TABLEX::getF2).sum();
```

Or you can create a custom class for this, which works for any number N of sums you want to get:

```
class SumFunction<T> {

    private List<Function<T, Double>> functions;
    private List<Double> results;

    @SafeVarargs
    public SumFunction(Function<T, Double>... functions) {
        this.functions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(functions));
        this.results = IntStream.of(0, this.functions.size()).mapToObj(i -> 0d).collect(toList());
    }

    public void merge(SumFunction<T> other) {
        //you can't check that the other.functions behaves as the same, I think
        assert results.size() == other.results.size();
        IntStream.range(0, results.size())
                 .forEach(i -> this.results.set(i, Double.sum(this.results.get(i), other.results.get(i))));
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        IntStream.range(0, this.functions.size())
                 .forEach(i -> this.results.set(i, Double.sum(this.results.get(i), this.functions.get(i).apply(t))));
    }

    public List<Double> getSums() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.results);
    }
}
```

that you call:

```
SumFunction s = list.stream()
                    .collect(() -> new SumFunction<TABLEX>(TABLEX::getF1, TABLEX::getF2), 
                             SumFunction::add, 
                             SumFunction::merge);

List<Double> sums = s.getSums();
```

---

According to the edit, you can create a static nested class that creates the grouping:

```
public static class TABLEXGrouping {
    Object f3;
    Object f4;

    public TABLEXGrouping(Object f3, Object f4) {
        this.f3 = f3;
        this.f4 = f4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TABLEXGrouping that = (TABLEXGrouping) o;
        return Objects.equals(f3, that.f3) &&
                Objects.equals(f4, that.f4);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(f3, f4);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return f3 + ", " + f4;
    }
}
```

then you group by this class, map the TABLEX instances to lists of 2 elements and reduce them to sum:

```
Map<TABLEX.TABLEXGrouping, List<Double>> map =
        list.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(t -> new TABLEX.TABLEXGrouping(t.getF3(), t.getF4()),
                                mapping(t -> Arrays.<Double>asList(t.f1, t.f2),
                                        reducing(Arrays.asList(0d, 0d),
                                                 (l1, l2) -> Arrays.asList(Double.sum(l1.get(0), l2.get(0)), Double.sum(l1.get(1), l2.get(1)))
                                                )
                                         )
                                )
                    );
```

Output:

```
{c, d=[7.0, 8.0], a, b=[2.0, 4.0]}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to make it more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to group by f3,f4 i shall create a lambda function which contains arrays value say f3,f4

```
 Function<TABLEX,List<Object>> compositeKey = TABLEXS ->Arrays.<Object>asList(TABLEXS.getF3(),TABLEXS.getF4());

 Map<List<Object>, Object> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> {
 Object sumOfF1 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.summarizingLong(TABLEX 
->TABLEX.getF1()),
                                   getF1Sum -> String.format("%s", getF1Sum .getSum())));

Object sumOfF2 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.summarizingLong(TABLEX 
->TABLEX.getF2()), getF2Sum -> String.format("%s", getF2Sum .getSum())));
Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            result.put("SumOfF1",sumOfF1);
            result.put("SumofF2",sumOfF2);
             return result;
        })));
```